# Is it possible to drive the @Size "max" value from a properties file?

Tags: spring, validation, controller, size, properties-file

I'm using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE. I have a model with the following attribute

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Size(max=15)
private String name;
```

I validate the model in my controller my running

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView save(final Model model,
                         @Valid final MyForm myForm,
```

I would like to have the "15" value come from a properties file instead of hard-coded, but am unclear if that's possible or how its done. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The constant expression that you provide as a value for the `max` attribute is added at compile time. There is no way to change the value of an annotation at runtime. Setting it from a properties file you read is therefore not possible

What you can do instead is to create and register your own `Validator` for the your class that has that field. For example,

```
public class MyValidator implements Validator {

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        MyObject obj = (MyObject) target;
        int length = getProperties().get("max.size");
        if (obj.name.length() > length) {
            errors.rejectValue("name", "String length is bigger than " + length);
        }
    }

    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return clazz == MyOBject.class;
    }
}
```

Take a look at [Spring's validation framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html).