# How to load any property files at compile time with spring?

Tags: java, spring

I want to load any property files in spring POJO classes.

Actually, I want to use any properties from property file in `@Size`, `@NotNull` or any validation annotations in spring model classes.

But the issue is that `@Size`, `@NotNull` etc annotation are invoked at compile-time whereas any property file's data are invoked at runtime.

Even, I want to use in the `max` parameter of `@Size` which accepts the only constant integer. How can I load value and cast it to Integer as a constant value?

And I can use custom validator or any custom annotation to solve the issue but as per the organization policy, I can't use much customization.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36811838/loading-compile-time-constants-from-properties-file

Comment: I think it's not much related to my concern. My concern is with spring POJO classes and application.properties file.

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154720/is-it-possible-to-drive-the-size-max-value-from-a-properties-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to drive the @Size "max" value from a properties file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154720/is-it-possible-to-drive-the-size-max-value-from-a-properties-file)

Comment: It's not possible. To work it requires the annotation to be spring-aware and to accept a string as a parameter.

Comment: I tried with customization and it works well, but I can't use customization because of the policy of my organization. can anyone help me with any different solution??

Comment: Just validate in a `@PostConstruct`?

Comment: HI @ChristopherSchneider, can you explain more related to `@PostContruct` with the small example of validation which uses property files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an additional solution to this problem that we can use a class of constants instead of the property file.

I can use this constants file anywhere in my workspace whereas property file can't use at `Size.max` property of the model validation

**CommonConstants.java**

```
public class CommonConstants 
{
    public static final int NAME=4;
    public static final int ROLE=2;
}
```

**Employee.java**

```
private int id;
@Size(max = CommonConstants.NAME, message = "length exceeds : name")
private String name;
@Size(max = CommonConstants.ROLE, message = "length exceeds : role")
private String role;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}
```

**EmployeeController.java**

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeController.class);

private Map<Integer, Employee> emps = null;

public EmployeeController() {
    emps = new HashMap<Integer, Employee>();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/emp/save.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveEmployeeAction(@Valid Employee employee, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) 
  {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        logger.info("Returning empSave.jsp page");
        return "empSave";
    }
    logger.info("Returning empSaveSuccess.jsp page");
    model.addAttribute("emp", employee);
    emps.put(employee.getId(), employee);
    return "empSaveSuccess";
  }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I also ran into this problem, and if a properties file is a must, we need to create our own custom validation.